# Python Tkinter Treeview (How link parent and child)

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Hello I would like to do something like that, can you suggest a function that will allow me to do this? Thanks

What I have on the window:

```
- GrandParents
    - Parents
        Child1
        Child2
    - Parents2
        Child3
- GrandParents2
    Children
```

...

What I would like to get in the console:

```
GrandParents_Parents_Child1
GrandParents_Parents_Child2
GrandParents_Parents2_Child3
GrandParents2_Children
...
```

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Treeview")
entry = tk.Entry(root)
tv = ttk.Treeview()
menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff = False)

def add():
    if not tv.exists(entry.get()) and entry.get() != "":
        if tv.selection() == ():
            tv.insert('', 'end', entry.get(), text=entry.get())
        else:
            tv.insert(tv.selection()[0], 'end', entry.get(), text=entry.get())

def popup(event):
    menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

def unselect(event):
    if len(tv.selection()) > 0:
        tv.selection_remove(tv.selection()[0])

menu.add_command(label="Add", command=add)
tv.bind("<Button-3>", popup)
tv.bind("<Button-1>", unselect)

tv.pack()
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show us the code snippet you used for displaying tree view?

Comment: it's ok i've added my code. ;)

Comment: Nobody have the answer ? x)

Answer (score 1):

I have provided a small example how you can achive this. Use the optional parameter *iid* of an item to identfy it and use the *parent(item)* method of the Treeview to get the [information](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Treeview")
entry = tk.Entry(root)
tv = ttk.Treeview()
#list of all parents of the selected item
parents = []
def get_parent(item):
    parent = tv.parent(item)
    parents.append(parent) #add parent to list
    if tv.parent(parent): #if parent has a parent
        get_parent(parent)
def get_tree(event):
    selected = tv.selection()
    if tv.parent(selected):
        get_parent(selected)
    print(f'the parantes of {selected} are {parents}')
    parents.clear()#clear list after printing
##insert some items and use the optional parameter idd i.e. Grandparent
tv.insert('', 'end', 'Grandparent', text='Grandparent')
tv.insert('Grandparent', 'end', 'Parent', text='Parent')
tv.insert('Parent', 'end', 'Child', text='Child')
##bind treeview select event
tv.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', get_tree)
menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff = False)

def add():
    if not tv.exists(entry.get()) and entry.get() != "":
        if tv.selection() == ():
            tv.insert('', 'end', entry.get(), text=entry.get())
        else:
            tv.insert(tv.selection()[0], 'end', entry.get(), text=entry.get())

def popup(event):
    menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

def unselect(event):
    if len(tv.selection()) > 0:
        tv.selection_remove(tv.selection()[0])

menu.add_command(label="Add", command=add)
tv.bind("<Button-3>", popup)
tv.bind("<Button-1>", unselect)

tv.pack()
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mhmm That doesn't really answer my question , but it's part of it.

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: It's ok I managed to do what I wanted with your code and the get_all_children of another thread that talks about Treeview on stackoverflow. Thanks again for your time. 